# This population will be extinct or not

Tags: probability

There is a group of people, each individual with probability $0.2$ has $0$ child, with probability $0.6$ has $1$ child, with $0.2$ has $2$ children, then after a very long(you can think as infinity long) time

A This group will be extinct
B This group will have a population of infinity
C The population of this group will be stable in a range
D Not enough information

My solution:
Intuitively, Because Expectation=$0.2*0+0.6*1+0.2*0.2=1$, so I feel it should be stable in a range. But why this is wrong?

I want to get a feeling why it will be extinct? Or how can we explain it intuitively?

Comment: Doesn't each person have _two_ parents, making the population half in size each generation, and eventually exctinct?

Comment: how did you get to the "stable in a range"? if everyone has one child (in average), thus there is infinity people of infinitely generations. (But I don't understand the sense of the question and answers)

Comment: This is a special case of branching process, look out this question for some insight: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295353/branching-process

Comment: One can show that almost surely, there will be extinction of the population if the mean of the reproduction distribution is less than or equal to $1$, provided $0$ child is possible. Unfortunately i can't type the proof, but it has to do with fixed point of the generating function of the reproduction law. See for example http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~csplash/data/notes/2011-24.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This is a case of [Gambler's ruin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin).  If you keep trying long enough, with probability $1$ the group will go extinct.  As written, the question does not specify how many generations you try for, so you might have a good chance of still having some individuals.

Comment: After a very long time

Comment: @nkhuyu $O(pop^2)$

Comment: as opposed to $(\ln(pop))$ if the expectation is below $1$